# Navigating a <router-outlet> from its parent

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, router-outlet

I'm trying to change te component active in a  from its parent. Looking how [Ionic does it](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-the-root-component), I assume that it should be something similar to this (very simplified):

```js
@Component({
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class MyComponent {
    @ViewChild(RouterOutlet) router: RouterOutlet;

    foo() {
        this.router.navigate('/route');
    }
}
```

Obviously this cannot work. Is there any way to do something similar?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `@ViewChild(RouterOutlet) router: RouterOutlet;`, you should inject it in the component's constructor. And instead of using `RouterOutlet`, you use `Router`. Your component will looks like this:

```
@Component({
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})

export class MyComponent {
    constructor(router: Router) {}

    foo() {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/route');
    }
}
```

And also, you need to make sure that you have already included `RouterModule` and the list of your URLs in your app module.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried that before, but didn't work. I just realised that it was because of a Guard... :(